# I can't make rich menu in LINE by using messaging api

Tags: powershell

I want to make make rich menu and try to run the code that is in docs.The code is this.

```
curl.exe -v -X POST https://api.line.me/v2/bot/richmenu -H 'Authorization: Bearer {my channel access token} -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"size":{"width":2500,"height":1686},"selected":false,"name":"Test the default rich menu","chatBarText":"Tap to open","areas":[{"bounds":{"x":0,"y":0,"width":1666,"height":1686},"action":{"type":"uri","label":"Tap area A","uri":"https://www.python.jp/train/index.html"}}]}'
```

And then it returns  {"message":"The request body could not be parsed as JSON (line: 1, column: 3)"}* Connection #0 to host api.line.me left intact.I can't understand why this error occer.
Whole returned text is this.

```
Note: Unnecessary use of -X or --request, POST is already inferred.
*   Trying 147.92.249.148:443...
* Connected to api.line.me (147.92.249.148) port 443 (#0)
* schannel: disabled automatic use of client certificate
* ALPN: offers http/1.1
* ALPN: server accepted http/1.1
* using HTTP/1.1
> POST /v2/bot/richmenu HTTP/1.1
> Host: api.line.me
> User-Agent: curl/8.0.1
> Accept: */*
> Authorization: Bearer 39agOWZRzGsJjTKMCHoaoIpjE5W9GDuQd0tT0RKv3Kdc9onMrqcwq758jAEztD+22f41jZtgdTO/FOfDi0GdxkcO63KCPRb0BrNCynQsokXJpM1XUMDQsKj7qW3StyfYxHwzVDQsCStwORWBH6ztQAdB04t89/1O/w1cDnyilFU=
> Content-Type: application/json
> Content-Length: 230
>
< HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
< server: legy
< cache-control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
< content-type: application/json
< date: Wed, 27 Sep 2023 23:24:26 GMT
< expires: 0
< pragma: no-cache
< x-content-type-options: nosniff
< x-frame-options: DENY
< x-line-request-id: 0a3b64be-2e00-4d90-9493-13338982f5e2
< x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
< content-length: 79
<
{"message":"The request body could not be parsed as JSON (line: 1, column: 3)"}* Connection #0 to host api.line.me left intact
```

I use Windows 11 and use Windows PowerShell.

I changed first content in json of the -d option.This means I exchange "size":{・・・} and "name":"・・・" .